# Macro/Code to copy and transpose paste based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Good day everyone.

I am facing a roadblock currently with an excel file that I'm creating for an assignment.

In my file, I need cells `C6:C13` from sheet 'Input' to be transpose pasted in the `Database` sheet rows `C8:J8 or C9:J9 or C10:J10` etc. based on: the content of cell `C5` in the 'Input' sheet should match the one of the rows in column B.

You can find the file here: http://tinyurl.com/oz7w97g

Thanks in advance!!!

Edit 2: My problem now is, it is pasting the data in whichever cell is selected in the 'Database' sheet. For example, if J13 is selected, it will automatically paste the data in J13:Q13 without searching for the right cell.

Edit 3: I figured it out, changed 'As String' to 'As Date' and it works. To make it more efficient, is there a way I could reduce the length of this code because bear in mind there are 72 different rows it needs to refer to so I will need to type out 'If' and 'ElseIf' 72 times.

```
Sub Code1()

Dim strCriteria As Date

strCriteria = Cells(5, "C").Value

Range("C6:C13").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Database").Select

If strCriteria = "01-01-2015" Then
    Range("C7").Select
ElseIf strCriteria = "01-01-2016" Then
    Range("C8").Select
ElseIf strCriteria = "01-01-2017" Then
    Range("C9").Select
End If



Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
Sheets("Input").Select
Range("D13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("C13").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: what have you tried so far, and where does your code give an error? please include your code into your question so people can see what might be wrong instead of attaching the file by url.

Comment: As you can see above, it only pastes the values. I need to add a few lines which enable it to paste based on the contents of cell C5 in 'Input' and match it to one of the rows in column B in 'Database'

Comment: What's the criteria that determines the logic? What condition should satisfy C5 exactly? What effort did you make to overcome your roadblock (relevant searches)

Comment: Cell C5 in 'Input' sheet will consist of a date which then should be matched to the pre-typed dates in column B of the 'Database' sheet. The contents of the remaining cells C6:C13 should then be transpose pasted next to the relevant date in column B of sheet 'Database'.

Comment: Please read Edit 3 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I see your changes. One thing you can do is lookup the destination cell based on the criteia of cell C5. I created a VLOOKUP in cell C4 that will lookup the destination based on the date in cell C5.
[image]

The formula in cell C4 is:`=VLOOKUP(C5,F5:G7,2,FALSE)`. The table has 1/1/2015 in cell F5 and "C7" in cell G5. The other dates and cells would follow directly below it.

You can create the lookup table on another sheet if you want.

Here is the new code that then uses the looked up value in cell C4:

```
Sub Code1()

    Dim strCell As String

    strCell = Cells(4, "C").Value

    Range("C6:C13").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Database").Select

    Range(strCell).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("Input").Select
    Range("D13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C13").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Cell C5 consists of a date (for eg. Jan-15)
The column 'B' in the 'Database' sheet consists of the dates for 72 months which have already been typed out. So it should basically check the date entered in the 'Input' sheet and match it and paste accordingly.

Comment: Please check my original post, I have added a modified version of your code there. My problem now is, it is pasting the data in whichever cell is selected in the 'Database' sheet. For example, if J13 is selected, it will automatically paste the data in J13:Q13 without searching for the right cell.

Comment: Thank you dev! That works great! Couldn't be happier.
Will surely post back if I run into anything else but for now I'm set.